# confusion about transaction.atomic() in Django

Tags: django, transactions

I have a view in which I do a series of model saves like so:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    modelA.save()
    modelB.save() 
    ...
```

I want all the saves to be done at once, but when I check the database after executing `modelA.save()` and before executing `modelB.save()` I see that the table `modelA` writes to has been changed, that is the write to `modelA` has been committed to the db. I thought all the writes in a `transaction.atomic()` block would be committed together at the end. What am I missing? I'm using django 1.10 and Oracle 12g. Thanks

Comment: how do you check the database after executing modelA.save() and before executing modelB.save()? What you are describing is the expected behaviour

Comment: I query sql_developer.

Comment: Of course with a query. What I meant was that you are doing:
with transaction.atomic():
    modelA.save()
    ### Here you query the database
    modelB.save()

somehow you are interrupting the execution.

To get to what I uderstand that you expect to see, you need to open the transaction in COMMITED READ mode. I guess that the Oracle Django's backend have a property for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using multiple databases, you should specify which database to use with `using`:

```
with transaction.atomic(using='my_db'):
    modelA.save()
    modelB.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
transaction.set_autocommit(False, using='my_db')
modelA.save()
modelB.save()
transaction.commit(using='my_db')
transaction.set_autocommit(True, using='my_db')
```

My issue was that a constraint on the db table in question meant the saves had to be done as one transaction. For some reason transaction.atomic() didn't work...